# HDFS - How to force replication factor

Tags: hadoop, replication, hdfs

The replication factor used to be set to 3, but is now 1. How do I force the replication factor to the cluster? In other words, initiate a process to delete now over-replicated file blocks?

Answer (score 4):

It's better if you allow it to happen automtically overtime but
If you want to force the new replication factor to be effective quickly, may be you could run the balancer script using,

> $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-balancer.sh

This should re-balance the blocks across the cluster.

Or, you can probably do this for the existing files,

```
hadoop fs -setrep -R 1 /
```

, which will probably set the replication levels of files recursively inside /